# Images are not resized and logs show a 'getMediaStream' pipeline error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

The images uploaded to Media library are 1000x1000 in size, whenever I try to access those images with *mw*, *mh* params I get a error logged and the image is not resized but the original served.

```
   ERROR Could not run the 'getMediaStream' pipeline for '/sitecore/media library/BannerAssets/FebBanners/mybanner'. Original media data will be used.
    Exception: System.FormatException
    Message: Input string was not in a correct format.
    Source: mscorlib
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetIntSetting(String name, Int32 defaultValue)
       at Sitecore.Resources.Media.TransformationOptions..ctor()
       at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaOptions.GetTransformationOptions()
       at Sitecore.Resources.Media.ResizeProcessor.Process(GetMediaStreamPipelineArgs args)
       at (Object , Object[] )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media.GetStreamFromPipeline(MediaOptions options, Boolean& canBeCached)
```

sample url:
 *mydomain.com/~/media/mydit/product%20images/v/clock.png?sc_revision=bw91698947a6620893461de1aec28fdf&mw=150&mh=150*

update: *fixed after removing an old PNGCrush.config file from the server.*

Comment: Can you provide a sample URL for the image you are trying to access or sample code that you think is throwing this error?

Comment: sure, I have added an example

Comment: I think I found the issue, there was an old PNGCrush.config file that was trying to get into getMediastream pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Fxed by removing an old PNGCrush.config file from the server.